# parse whereequalto return all row android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'am trying to do search in parse. But I'm getting all rows. I have only one row with the name equal to Android.

```
ParseQuery<Group> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Group.class);
    query.whereEqualTo("name", "Android");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Group>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Group> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                    Group group = objects.get(i);
                    groupList.add(group);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            Log.d("Size", "" + objects.size());
        }
    });
```

Comment: You'll have to show us a Parse Dashboard to prove your data is as you say it is

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Y2mpI

Comment: I have tried different version of parse library, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

[`whereEqualTo` returns a new Query object](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), not modifies in place.

Try the following

```
ParseQuery.getQuery(Group.class)
    .whereEqualTo("name", "Android")
    .findInBackground(new FindCallback<Group>() {
```

Or, if you need to keep the query object

```
ParseQuery<Group> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Group.class).whereEqualTo("name", "Android");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Group>() {
```

Comment: Tried both ways?

Comment: Sorry, extra semicolon first way. Well, this is how you filter the data. I can't say why it is not working

Comment: Sorry, I fix it. I'm using http instead of https. So get 302 moved to https. Then request is made as GET https instead of POST https. Parameter are lost. Server receive request without any filter. I just monitor traffic and found it. Thanks.